# Truffle migration with contract argument

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I have have many examples and in the 2_deploy_contracts.js providing simple arguments like address, string is all good.

However I am trying to deploy [this example](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol) and it has a `MintableToken _token` as an argument. How do I provide that in 2_deploy_contracts.js?

Comment: For contracts you have to send the contract address.

Answer (score 1):

You can either deploy setting a variable to the contract instance via `await`, or neater still, use the `.then` method of the promise to chain the deployments, giving you access to the instance (and so the address) in the deployment of your second contract.

```
const contractOne = artifacts.require('ContractOne')
    , contractTwo = artifacts.require('ContractTwo')

module.exports = deployer => 
  deployer.deploy(contractOne)
    .then(contOne => deployer.deploy(contractTwo, contOne.address))
```

And so here, `contractOne` would be your mintable token contract.